# Why alert dismiss does not work when it is triggered again?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I show the loader before making a request to the server. After the answer is received - the function of stopping the loader is called.

The first time it works fine. But when you re-enter the page, the loader does not turn off and it remains to spin forever. (I believe this is due to the fact that the request is already happening much faster, and there is no significant delay).

For clarity, I added markers to my code.
Please tell me what the problem is and how can I fix it?

```
var alert : UIAlertController?

func showLoader(){
    self.alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: NSLocalizedString("pleaseWait", comment: "Текст ожидания загрузки"), preferredStyle: .alert)

    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    self.alert!.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    present(self.alert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    Logger.Log("Alert is presented")
}

func stopLoader(){
    if let _ = self.alert {
        Logger.Log("Loader isBeingPresented = \(self.alert!.isBeingPresented)")
        Logger.Log("Loader isBeingDismissed1 = \(self.alert!.isBeingDismissed)")

        self.alert!.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        Logger.Log("Loader isBeingDismissed2 = \(self.alert!.isBeingDismissed)")

        self.alert = nil

        Logger.Log("Loader dismissed")
    } else {
        Logger.Log("Alert failed")
    }
}
```

> ** Selected: 2019-03-01 17:00:00 +0000 **  //first try
>   ** Alert is presented **
>   ** File exist! **
>   ** requestDone **
>   ** Loader isBeingPresented = false **
>   ** Loader isBeingDismissed1 = false **
>   ** Loader isBeingDismissed2 = true **
>   ** Loader dismissed **
>   ** Selected: 2019-03-01 17:00:00 +0000 **  //second try
>   ** Alert is presented **
>   ** File exist! **
>   ** requestDone **
>   ** Loader isBeingPresented = false **
>   ** Loader isBeingDismissed1 = false **
>   ** Loader isBeingDismissed2 = false **
>   ** Loader dismissed **

Comment: re enter page means the viewdidload is called or not

Comment: `loadingIndicator` is a local variable - where/how do you stop it?  You don't have a reference outside of the `showLoader` function

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes of course. I go to another View Controller and then come back. viewDidLoad call is called again.

Comment: @alex-kirov: Are you sure you are calling `stopLoader` and `showLoader` on main thread?? Add one more debug statement and print `Thread.currentThread` and check if its always called on main thread

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, but it is only an indicator. It is inside the alert that I am trying to dismiss

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari print of thread in the StopLoader method showed:  
** <NSThread: 0x6000008cc440>{number = 1, name = main} ** // first try  
** <NSThread: 0x6000008cc440>{number = 1, name = main} ** // second try. And it presented in the same thread

Comment: Your dismiss call appears to be wrong. It should be self.dismiss instead of self.alert!.dismiss in the stopLoader method.

Comment: @Rishabh It gives exactly the same result. (

Comment: Well then how and when are you calling the show and stop methods?

Comment: @Rishabh I answered below (in your answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you should implement the completion blocks:

1) viewDidLoad calls `controller.start()`
2) presenter calls `view.showLoader()` with a completion callback
3) In callback you start `NetworkController.getfiles()`
4) when NetworkController.getfiles() is done, `controller.callback` calls `view.stopLoader()`

Comment: Yes, I tried it. The result remains the same.  
1) in viewDidLoad methode I call controller.start()  
2) then in controller.start() I call NetworkController.getfiles() after 
presenter.waitRespond()   
3) presenter just call view.showLoader()  
4) when NetworkController.getFiles() is done, it calls controller.callback

Comment: 5) in controller.callback i call presenter.requestDone()
6) presenter just call stopLoader()

Comment: After the stoploader method gets called for second time, try to print the following self.presentingViewController
                    self.presentedViewController
                    self.alert?.isBeingPresented after the dismiss line gets called. Also implement the dismiss call with the completion handler and do self.alert = nil in the completion block as well.

Comment: self.presentingViewController is nil both times. self.alert?.isBeingPresented is false both times. But  self.presentedViewController exist first time, and is nil second time. Also I tried to call self.dismiss in DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) and it works fine. But I think it is not good solution.

Comment: Ok that makes sense the self.presentedViewController is nil second time means the alert is not yet presented and thats why the dismiss call has no effect. You should implement the completion in both present and dismiss calls, that should solve the issue. Also the view.showLoader should be called before the Network request starts, is that how it goes?

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand what you mean.
"You should implement the completion in both present and dismiss calls"

Comment: Yes, sure. showLoader called before Network request.

Comment: If you look at the present and dismiss calls, you will see there is a completion parameter that you have given as nil in both. The completion parameter is a closure that tells you that the present call or dismiss call is now complete. This way you can be sure once you are trying to dismiss an alert that it has definitely been presented and avoid calling dismiss unless the presentation is complete.

Comment: Yes, I added call controller.executeRequest in complet section of present. Now it work fine, thanks. You did a good job :)